# Adobe Flash Professional CS5 installation issue in windows vista

Tags: windows-vista, installation, flash-cs5

I am facing a wired problem with windows vista installer while installing Adobe Flash Professional CS5(trail version).

After clicking the 'set up' file immediately I'm getting an alert message like `Installer has detected that a machine restart is pending. It is recommended that you quit the installer, restart and try again.`. The same file is installing fine for windows XP without any issue.

I tried some solutions found in some forums and also tried a solution specified in the Adobe site but none of them solved my issue.

If anybody familiar with this issue then please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what could be the reason for this but the issue got resolved. Yesterday I tried many ways but nothing worked for me, I just tried once again now to install the Flash CS5, this time successfully installed without any issue.